# Aligning five divs next to each other

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm currently making a website where you can find results of Formula One races. To do so, I want to make a result page for each Grand Prix, where the results are being shown in 5 boxes next to each other. Like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

But right now it looks like this

```
1 2
   3
4    5
```

This is the HTML code I use:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="fp1">FP1</div>
    <div id="fp2">FP2</div>
    <div id="fp3">FP3</div>
    <div id="qual">Qual</div>
    <div id="race">Race</div>
</div> <!--End wrap div-->
```

And this the CSS I use:

```
#wrap{
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #000;
border: 1px solid white;
}
#fp1{
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #333;
float: left;
}
#fp2{
margin-left: 20%;
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #666;
}
#fp3{
margin-left: 40%;
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #333;
}
#qual{
margin-left: 60%;
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #666;
float: right;
}
#race{
width: 20%;
height: 600px;
background-color: #333;
float: right;
}
```

Anybody who knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/KAwEz/

```
#fp1{
  width: 20%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #333;
  float: left;
}
 .....
```

You can use a generic class, since styles are repetitive. see this for efficient one: http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/KAwEz/1/

Comment: Well that was easier than expected.. I did it the way above 'cause that's part of how I did it with 3 divs.. Anyway thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

else you can follow inline-block method, and further in time column and display:flex will be usefull:
http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/IosFk

```
#wrap {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#wrap, .wrap {

  /* for test */
  height:200px;
overflow:auto;}
.wrap {
  -moz-column-width:300px;
  -webkit-column-width:300px;
  column-width:300px;
}
#wrap div {
  white-space:normal;
  display:inline-block;
}
#wrap div , .wrap div {
/* for test */
  width:300px;
  height:100%;
  background:#999;
}
```

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="fp1">FP1</div>
    <div id="fp2">FP2</div>
    <div id="fp3">FP3</div>
    <div id="qual">Qual</div>
    <div id="race">Race</div>
</div> <!--End wrap div-->
<div class="wrap" >
    <div id="fp1">FP1</div>
    <div id="fp2">FP2</div>
    <div id="fp3">FP3</div>
    <div id="qual">Qual</div>
    <div id="race">Race</div>
</div> <!--End wrap div-->
```

If you want no scroll, divide 100%/numbers of boxes (fine if window not too small :) )
cheers

Answer (score 0):

One more thing i noticed other than float:left regarding structure is you can use margin-left without % and give common margin-left like 20px